# The charge of tunneling Bogoliubov quasiparticles

Tags: superconductivity, quasiparticles

There are some concepts regarding charge and quasiparticles I can't fully reconcile with one another.

Commonly in superconducting literature, one will find that a Cooper pair is made out of two electrons, and thus has a charge of $-2e$. This is reflected in, say, the magnetic flux quantum being $h/2e$.

But it is often also written that a Cooper pair can be broken up into two Bogolyubov quasiparticles, for example by a photon of energy $2\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the superconducting gap. This would then promote two quasiparticles to the gap edge $\Delta$.

From BCS theory we know that these quasiparticles are not purely electron-like; they are electron-hole superpositions. In fact, at the gap edge, this is an equal superposition, so that the quasiparticles are chargeless. But if a Cooper pair of charge $-2e$ gets broken up into two chargeless quasiparticles, charge is not conserved. Is that correct? Maybe that's okay because BCS theory does not conserve particle number?

But when it comes to something we measure I feel less at ease, such as when we allow the quasiparticles to tunnel and can detect the effects in experiments. For example tunneling of quasiparticles between two superconductors, or between a superconductor and a metal. The former case comes up a lot in the context of superconducting qubits such as Cooper pair boxes and transmons. There the offset charge on the island shifts exactly by $1e$ whenever a quasiparticle tunnels. So apparently now the quasiparticles do have a definite charge, rather than being chargeless? Is this (in handwavy fashion) due to the superposition state 'being measured'?

My confusion came about from a recent publication named [A superconductor free of quasiparticles for seconds by Mannila et al. 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00484). Here they monitor, in real time, quasiparticles tunneling from the superconductor to a normal metal. As shown in figure 1d, each tunneling event is associated with a change in the charge of the island in a discrete step of $1e$. What confuses me even more, however, is that this can be $\pm1 e$, as the curve shows. To explain this, they write the quasiparticles can tunnel out either as a hole or as an electron. But if a Cooper pair has charge $-2e$, gets broken up into two chargeless quasiparticles, and subsequently one of them tunnels out as a hole and the other as an electron, something feels off.

Is there a way to reconcile these concepts? Why do quasiparticles need to tunnel in units of $1e$? And why, for these physically measurable events, are we okay with letting charge conservation go? Is my problem seeing the Cooper pair as charge $-2e$?

[image]